# How to do formatting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

In SQL Server 2008, I have a query. When I use the `select` query on my `Student` table, I get a result set like this:

```
Total   Subject            Class
20       Chemistry          Standard -12
30        Physics           Standard -12
94        Biology           Standard -12
0         Maths             Standard -12

5       Chemistry           Standard -11
45       Physics            Standard -11
50       Biology            Standard -11
45        Maths             Standard -11
```

But now my requirement is that I need to format it differently - like this:

```
                   Chemistry Biology Physics Maths
Standard - 12     20       94      30      0
Standard - 11      5       50      45      45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have uniqu row for class and subject combination.

In this case you can use the below query -

```
select class,
       max(case
             when subject = 'Chemistry' then
              total
             else
              0
           end) as Chemistry,
       max(case
             when subject = 'Biology' then
              total
             else
              0
           end) as Biology,
       max(case
             when subject = 'Physics' then
              total
             else
              0
           end) as Physics,
       max(case
             when subject = 'Maths' then
              total
             else
              0
           end) as Maths
  from your_table_name
 group by class
```

Comment: Dear Pratik,                                                          I tried with above query but it's not working for me. actually above result i got after applying group by on "class"  and total is a count of rows for that particular class.

Comment: @priyapatel I am sorry I didn't get why this query is not working for your case?

Comment: I have little idea that i am suppose to use "pivot" to achieve this.

Comment: @priyapatel if you have this constaint to use `Pivot` then there is no problem But i am sure this above query also will give the same result as per shown in question.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. i tried your query for the same and it worked fine. but i could not understand why do we use "MAX"? will you please explain ??

Comment: actually we want to show one row for each class so we are taking group by in this case. with group by one column we want other columns also so that's why we need to use any aggregate function.

Comment: since we will have uniqueness for class and subject combination in our table then if we use `sum` or `max` will not create any problem.
because we will have only one value whereas we are taking `max` out of that and that's why we will get the same value indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/071f17/8)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Class,
      Subject,
      Total 
      FROM Student ) s
pivot ( SUM(Total)
        FOR [Subject] IN ([Chemistry], [Physics], [Biology], [Maths])
       ) piv
```

Result:

```
|        CLASS | CHEMISTRY | PHYSICS | BIOLOGY | MATHS |
--------------------------------------------------------
| Standard -11 |         5 |      45 |      50 |    45 |
| Standard -12 |        20 |      30 |      94 |     0 |
```